# Using Doctype let scrollTop return 0, why?

Tags: javascript, dom, doctype

When I put this Doctype in my documents `document.body.scrollTop` returns zero.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Why is that?

Comment: Which browser? On which element?

Comment: both IE and FF.. document.body.scrollTop;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use that Doctype, you'll put every current browser in the so-called [Almost Standards mode](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/), without it you'll be in Quirks Mode.

As you can read on [this page](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow),

> [m]ost browsers provide `window.pageXOffset/pageYOffset`. These are completely reliable. Once again, Internet Explorer is the odd one out, as it does not provide these properties. Internet Explorer and some other browsers will provide `document.body.scrollLeft/Top`. In strict mode, IE 6 and a few other browsers, provide `document.documentElement.scrollLeft/Top`.

A script provided there calculates the value you want:

```
function getScrollXY() {
  var scrOfX = 0, scrOfY = 0;
  if( typeof( window.pageYOffset ) == 'number' ) {
    //Netscape compliant
    scrOfY = window.pageYOffset;
    scrOfX = window.pageXOffset;
  } else if( document.body && ( document.body.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollTop ) ) {
    //DOM compliant
    scrOfY = document.body.scrollTop;
    scrOfX = document.body.scrollLeft;
  } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollTop ) ) {
    //IE6 standards compliant mode
    scrOfY = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    scrOfX = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
  }
  return [ scrOfX, scrOfY ];
}
```

Another interesting article appeared on QuirksMode, [A tale of two viewports](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html).

Comment: but what then if I want to set the scroll position mysself? window.pageYOffset is readonly?

Comment: got it! :) window.scroll(x, y);

Comment: @user: All current browsers (including IE 6) support (the non-standard) [`window.scrollTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.scrollTo).