# How to set the main page's DOCTYPE declaration in Vaadin

Tags: scroll, doctype, vaadin

I'm having issues with scroll offset detection that seem to be related with the DOCTYPE declaration:

[Using Doctype let scrollTop return 0, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815283/using-doctype-let-scrolltop-return-0-why)

As I am using Vaadin, I need to have it strip off this declaration from the main page.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the doctype by overriding AbstractApplicationServlet.writeAjaxPageHtmlHeadStart() (i.e by extending ApplicationServlet and referencing your implementation in web.xml).

**However:**

1. The problem you're seeing might not be related to the doctype at all!
2. Vaadin really must not be in quirks-mode.

Regarding 1: Are you trying to read scrollTop for the entire document? Vaadin applications often scroll within the main div in which it is rendered, not the whole page.

Comment: Hi Marc, indeed you must be right. Thanks very much for that. Do you, by any chance, happen to know how/if it is possible to get the main div's scroll offset?