# Scroll back to top not working in IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-6

I have the following code:

```
// hide #back-top first
    $("#back-top").hide();

    // fade in #back-top
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {
                $('#back-top').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('#back-top').fadeOut();
            }
        });

        // scroll body to 0px on click
        $('#back-top a').click(function () {
            $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 900);
            return false;
        });
    });
```

When you click on back to top it work's fine in IE6 - but when the fadeIn and fadeOut 'back to top' doesn't seem to work in IE6.

Comment: I have personally given up on IE6. If it degrades nicely, I would ignore this very old and feeble browser

Comment: I would love to ignore it but most of the users for this site are corporate users so they are still using IE6.

Comment: So are mine. So they do not see the fade. Too bad.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`$(window).scrollTop()` is the one that worked for me in all the current browsers

or

```
window.scroll(x, y);
```

Comment: Also Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815283/using-doctype-let-scrolltop-return-0-why  and  http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=11965

Comment: the scroll worked, it is the fade that does not seems to work